# Silex: Pass a variable to a controller class

Tags: variables, controller, silex

I already managed to pass the parameters of a route to a class, using this:

```
$app-get('/{$id}', 'OwnClass\Bazinga::lizard');

class Bazinga {
  public function lizard($id, Application $app, Request $request) {
    return "Scissors cuts paper, paper covers rock, rock crushes lizard..."; }
```

But how do I pass a global variable to a class which is called by the controller?
Within a normal closure I'd use this...

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($globalvariable) { return "meep meep"; } );
```

I already managed to work out a workaround by a static variable within the class, but there must be a nicer way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `$app` container to share globals throught controlers (and other places):

```
$app->get('/{$id}', 'OwnClass\Bazinga::lizard');

$app['a.unique.identifier'] = $globalvariable;

class Bazinga {

    public function lizard($id, Application $app, Request $request) {
        $globalvariable = $app['a.unique.identifier'];
        return "Scissors cuts paper, paper covers rock, rock crushes lizard...";
    }

}
```